# Where does Google Drive cache metadata on my device?

Tags: google-drive

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 4. Google Drive appears to download thumbnails and other metadata from the web service. Where does it store this metadata on my device? I assume it would be in a Sqlite database, but I'm not sure. Any suggestions on where to look? Or does Google Drive pull the metadata through the API to the service every time the screen changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

base directory:

```
/data/data/com.google.android.apps.docs/
```

files explicitly stored on device:

```
.../files/fileinternal/<filehash>/<file>
```

cached files and thumbnails:

```
.../cache/diskCache/
```

metadata:

```
.../databases/
```

the drive-supported files (like docs, spreads, presos) are in `com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.<foo>` datadir